# I want to access the update variable which is in component.ts and i want to assign it to other variable outside the method.How to do it

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

service.ts

```
get_update(id:any): Observable<any[]>{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/vendor/'+id,options)
                        .map((res: Response) =>  res.json())
                        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.statusText));
}
```

component.ts

```
this.service.get_update(this.user).subscribe(update => this.update = update,
                                      error =>console.log(error));
```

I want to access the update variable which is in component.ts and i want to assign it to other variable outside the method.How to do it

Comment: What does not work with the code you posted?

Comment: it was not working in another method( in update).

Comment: Please provide the part of the code where the problem is. It's really difficult to tell what's wrong just by looking at this

Comment: Here the method(UPDATE value in component.ts) is working fine but my question is that i want to print in another method (update value).

Comment: In the `subscribe` you are assigning the value of `update` to `this.update`, so if you want to reuse that value somewhere else just call `this.update`

Comment: Please explain more precisely what's the problem is, even with reading the comments I don't see what's wrong and what you want

Comment: I have already tried it its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing this.update in some other method will not help as the value is getting assigned inside a callback and some other method will not wait for its execution resulting in null value.
Either you can have a function callback as an input for get_update method, such that when you get update value you can pass that value to the respective callback
or you can directly call the other method inside your callback passing the update value as input parameter.

Comment: Actually i was little bit confused so could you show me one example.

Comment: If you want to use the update value , which is set inside a callback, call the other method inside the callback and pass the parameter as input.  Like if the other method is test(), then this.service.get_update(this.user).subscribe(update => test(update),
                                      error =>console.log(error));